# Relationship between $S$ and $S^{-1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations, order-theory

This is one of the problem I have been solving in Velleman's *How to Prove* book:

> Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$, and let $S$ be the transitive
>   closure of $R$. Prove that if $R$ is symmetric, then so is $S$. (Hint:
>   Asumme that $R$ is symmetric. Prove that $R \subseteq S^{-1}$ and
>   $S^{-1}$ is transitive. What can you conclude about $S$ and $S^{-1}$?)

Now I have proved both $R \subseteq S^{-1}$ and $S^{-1}$ is transitive. Now, what I cannot figure out is the relationship between $S$ and $S^{-1}$. Is there any general method for determining it ?

(Note: I haven't been taught Induction yet in the book, so I would like to stay away from it if there is any other way of determining the relationship between $S$ and $S^{-1}$)

Comment: The transitive closure $S$ of $R$ is the smallest transitive relation such that $R \subseteq S$, so if $S^{-1}$ is also a transitive relation, then what can you say about the relation between the two?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: work an example. For instance, on the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, let $R$ be the relation $$R(a, b)\iff \vert a-b\vert=2.$$ $R$ is symmetric; compute $S$ and $S^{-1}$ and compare them. Now make a guess . . .

Comment: Ok, that tells me that both $S$ and $S^{-1}$ are equal. But  I can't deduce it logically that $S \subseteq S^{-1}$ and $S^{-1} \subseteq S$ to prove that they are actually equal ? Any strategy on how to approach it?

Comment: Suppose $(a, b)\in S$; what does that tell you about how $a$ and $b$ are related to each other in terms of $R$? Using that, can you show $(a, b)\in S^{-1}$? And similarly in the other direction.

Comment: But it is not always the case that $(a,b) \in R$. There may be also instances where $(a,b) \notin R$ and this is the situation I'm stuck at.

Comment: I never said they were. :) How is $S$ defined? When do we know that $(a, b)\in S$?

Comment: Well, $S$ is defined as transitive closure of $R$ and we know that $R$ is symmetric. So, it can be either $(a,b) \in R$ or $(a,b) \notin R$. If it's not in $R$, then it was likely produced from the transitive relation. Well.. then what ? This seems to go towards induction which I haven't learned yet.

Comment: It has nothing to do with induction. Let's make this concrete: in the above example, is $(1, 7)$ in $S$? If so, why?

Comment: That's because either $(1,7)$ is in $R$ or it was produced from something like $(1,2)$ and $(2,7)$ ? And that $(1,2)$ and $(2,7)$ itself may be produced out of an transitive relation.

Comment: Be as concrete as possible: why, specifically, is (1, 7) in $S$? (1, 2) is not in $S$, so for what **specific reason** is (1, 7) in $S$?

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. $(1,7)$ can only be in $R$ since $R$ is symmetric. The only element built out of the transitive closure will be of the form $(a,a)$. Is this reasoning correct ?

Comment: No - what does symmetry of $R$ have to do with $(1, 7)$? $(1, 7)$ is also in the transitive closure $\hat{S}$ of the relation "$\hat{R}=\{(x, y): y-x=2\}$," which is not symmetric. For that matter, $(1, 7)$ is **not** in $R$ - it's in $S$. And I don't understand what "the only element built out of  . . ." means. I'm asking a very concrete question: how do you know that $(1, 7)$ is in $S$? If someone asked you, "Is $(1, 7)$ in the transitive closure of the relation $\vert x-y\vert=2$, and if so, why?", how would you answer them? Why is $(1, 7)$ in $S$ but not, say, $(1, 4)$?

Comment: All I can think  is because $1$ and $7$ are in $A$.

Comment: In the previous case what I meant to say was that the elements which are added to the set $S$ apart from $R$ will be of the form $(a,a)$.

Comment: That's not true - you need to re-read the definition of transitive closure. I believe you are thinking of the "reflexive closure" (not sure that's actually what it's called), which is a very different thing.

Comment: Ok, then probably I'm missing something unless you can explain the answer. Regarding your previous comment, on why I think $(1,7)$ is not in $R$ is because that it's given that $R$ is symmetric. So, if there is any element $(a,b) \in R$, then it will have $(b,a) \in R$ because of the symmetric property. Now the transitive closure of $R$ will additionally have $(a,a) \in S$ because of the transitive property. So, that's why I told $(1,7)$ will be in $R$.